# how to rails one to one relationship?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails.
Please help me how to create rails one to one relationship.
I have two table say abc and pqr.
in models I have declared `has_one:pqr` in abc model and `belongs_to:abc` in pqr model. I don't know how to write view and controller for "pqr".

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
bin/rails generate controller Pqr hello
```

It will generate a controller file, a view file, a functional test file and a helper for the view,. For more information have a look at [this article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate).

```
  exists  app/controllers/
  exists  app/helpers/
  create  app/views/pqr
  exists  test/functional/
  create  test/unit/helpers/
  create  app/controllers/pqr_controller.rb
  create  test/functional/pqr_controller_test.rb
  create  app/helpers/pqr_helper.rb
  create  test/unit/helpers/pqr_helper_test.rb
  create  app/views/pqr/hello.html.erb
```

You can add contents which will be used by your view, at your action `hello` in the controller `pqr_controller.rb`

```
class PqrController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    @content = "Hello World"
  end
end
```

Then if you want any other action and view corresponding to it later, say `show`, you could add an action in the controller and generate corresponding view at `app/views/pqr/show.html.erb`

```
class PqrController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    @content = "Hello World"
  end
  def show
    @contents = "Test"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have 2 tables: `person` and `dog`

First of all you need to create a `person_id` in `dog` table.
In models
Than you add `has_on :dog` in person.rb
and `belongs_to :person` in dog.rb

In controllers
To create a `dog` that belongs to a `person`. You need to create a person first.

```
@person = Person.new(params[:person])
@person.save
```

then create his dog.

```
@dog = Person.create_dog(params[:dog])
@dog.save
```

To access a person's dog you just have to type

```
@person.dog
```